# Form1 and form2 textbox and datagridview relation

Tags: datagridview, textbox

I have a form1 with datagridview.i want too send datagridview information from form1 to form2 textboxes but form2 does not define form1 and it's object.what should I do?!

Comment: how i should set DialogResult?

Answer (score 0):

define in form2 viriable to set amount and then open form2 with dialog mode

```
form2 f = new form2();
f.amount = value;
if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
f.amount;//Edited value  
}
```

note: must set DialogResult in form2 when user press ok to DialogResult.OK

Comment: Form1 has a datagridview.i want the ammount of datagrid selected rows go to textbox in form2 to edit the and again get it back to form1 datagrid